# mvc 4 app on a web server without mvc 4 installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, master-pages

So I just upgraded my website to a MVC 4 site from MVC 3. My Web host does not have MVC 4 installed but was advised that I can just upload the dlls and all will be alright. I was directed to this link which apparently can be applied when installed

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx

I did what is instructed on the following link but then I'm getting an error on my ViewExtensions which apparently (after a 2 hour research) is related to my upgrade (eg. http://s77.codeinspot.com/q/2109234) . Anyway this is the error being thrown.

> filterContext.Exception.Message :\hostingpath............... error
>   CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Torneyo.Infrastructure.Helpers.ViewExtensions.AccountProfile(System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage)'
>   and
>   'Torneyo.Infrastructure.Helpers.ViewExtensions.AccountProfile(System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage)'

Which doesn't make sense as it's the same and it's just coming from my viewextension class. Following is the part which is being called on my masterpage.

```
//-----------for master pages
        static public User AccountProfile(this System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage view)
        {
            return (Profile)view.ViewBag.AccountProfile;
        }
```

So these were all working perfectly before the upgrade on the webhost. It runs perfectly on my local before and after the upgrade. I'm not really sure what else I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have the correct binding redirects in your web.config. Chances are that parts of the app are referencing MVC3 and other parts are referencing MVC4. A binding redirect from MVC3 to MVC4 will "unify" everything to MVC4.

Check out the "upgrade" guide here: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Comment: All of them are correct. Btw, if it helps, I recreated the project with MVC 4 after I installed MVC 4 on my machine. So all of the webconfigs are all set up for MVC 4. I will, however, try adding the     <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" /> parts

Comment: Make sure you don't have different assemblies, force the csproj to have the same version as you have installed.

Comment: let me try wiping them out

Comment: this worked for me. Point nr. 7 in the upgrade guide seems to be very important :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. So I tried wiping out the DLLs and reinstalled it but it still doesn't work. What I had to do was to remove everything (Files in the wwwroot folder). And then published it again. Everything worked fine after that.